# IceFaces missing rime.css file

Tags: icefaces

we are using IceFaces 3.  This has been a problem since IceFaces 2.1, we just are slowing down to the point where i can start to work on it.  In our log files, we are getting thousands of these errors

```
May 14, 2011 9:29:43 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, rime.css, from library, org.icefaces.component.skins.
```

ignore the date, currently the server's time is backdated for testing.

what exactly am i missing here?  i can't find anything on google about this file missing and im not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

try this in h:head
    `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css"/>`
and this in h:body

```
<h:body styleClass="ice-skin-rime">
```

Update:
(http://jforum.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/20667.page): "With ICEfaces 3 you no longer need to have a reference to the CSS files in the head tag. This is now controlled with the context-param". 
 like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.icefaces.ace.theme</param-name>
    <param-value>rime</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Also, download the posted test case and see if the style gets loaded.
And ice Documentation:http://www.icesoft.org/projects/ICEfaces/documentation.jsf

Comment: i tried this, it didn't work.  i even upgraded from icefaces 3.0.0RC to 3.0.0 and same deal.  is there a document somewhere that explains what that rime.css file is and what im supposed to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar kind of issue, use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css"/>
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css"/>
```

make sure you are removing `.` in your `href`, now your `rime.css` file should be referenced, also make sure you have rime.css file in icefaces jars, you can see inside those jars using [java decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)

Comment: no, it didn't.  i think we are going to just ignore it until i can replace faces with something else.  most likely GWT

Answer (score 0):

Converting from icefaces 1.8 to icefaces 3, 
I have faced the same problem and solved it as below.

Refer to Icefaces-3.0.1-bin samples:

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That is all.